# Is the WRT54G limited at ~20 Mbps on the switch <-> uplink traffic?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, tomato, wrt54g

I have an old WRT54G which I wanted to reuse. The uplink is 100/100 Mbps but I only get about 20-30 Mbps between a wired device (laptop, RPi) connected to a switch port and Internet (when testing on the same site as with the bare access link).

The WRT54G has the latest (1.28) Tomato firmware and the tests were done with only this device connected.

Is there an inherent limitation on the internal switch <-> Internet bandwidth (due to hardware / NAT limitations rather than configuration)?

Comment: the 10+ years old cpu in wrt54g is so slow nowadays.

Comment: @IporSircer: slow enough not to handle 100 Mbps traffic between a 100 Mpbs switch port and the 100 Mbps WAN uplink port? I know about the history of this router, I wanted to have feedback about actual performances from the field.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a WRT54G in an application with 100 in and feeding several devices.  Using conventional "speed check" apps, the throughput was more than 60 but less that 100.

During this test there were few services running on the router, and it was using DDWRT.  Your mileage may vary, but for anyone looking into this, there is at least this data point.